# Comment formuler l'équivalent de « any two of three things » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, nombres

Comment formuler l'équivalent de « any two of three things » en français ? J'ai trouvé ces différentes réponses sur wordreference.com

1. *l'un des quelconques des X machins* ou *n'importe quels machins* ([référence](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1718580))
2. *n'importe lesquelles des X machins* ([référence](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1660200))
3. *n'importe quels X machins* ([référence](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1303624))
4. Aucuns X machins

Ces 4 conjectures sont-elles toutes admissibles et exactes? Y a-t-il des différences entre elles ?

---

Reformulation de la question par Stéphane Gimenez :

*Any two of three* est utilisé, par exemple, lorsque que trois signatures sont envisagées mais que seulement deux sont nécessaires :

> All withdrawals from banking accounts shall require any two of three signatures of Members appointed by Council for this purpose.

Et voici un autre exemple dans lequel trois éléments sont mentionnés, mais où seules les combinaisons de deux éléments sont envisagées :

> The instrument permits two-port measurements between any two of three front-panel inputs.

Comment exprimer la même chose de façon naturelle, à l'intérieur d'une phrase, en français ?

Comment: FL&U de Stackexchange n'est pas approprié pour juger de ce qui est proposé sur wordreference  qui n'est en aucune manière une référence mais juste un autre forum de discussion sur la langue. Je pense que le chat serait plus approprié.

Comment: @Laure: Merci. Je ne désire pas juger de ce qui y a été proposé. Or, je veux reconnaître toutes les traductions de **any # of x things**. A ceux qui ont voté pour la clôture, prière de me faire savoir pourquoi.

Comment: J'ai écrit la raison ci-dessus. Reformule tes questions de façon claire, par exemple en écrivant des phrases complètes et en évitant les "machins" et les "X" ; en demandant, par exemple, pourquoi on dit les choses ainsi, ou si c'est correct, et sans qu'on est besoin de se référer à wordreference pour avoir les phrases.

Comment: @Laure: c'est moi qui ai réécrit la question pour essayer d'en faire quelque chose. Les traductions d'expressions ou de tournures difficiles à formuler en français n'ont jamais été off-topic.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Copy paste from help " We are not a translation service, nor do we purport to be experts in languages other than French. Asking about the meaning of a difficult French sentence is fine. So is asking how to express an idea in idiomatic French. But please don't ask us to translate a text to or from another language." D'accord considérons qu'il ne s'agit pas de phrases entières, mais le PO aurait pu proposer une phrase en français. Je dois être plus sévère que toi !

Comment: @Laure: Ce type de question correspond exactement au « how to express an idea in idiomatic French ». Il ne s'agit en aucun cas de traduire des phrases entières. En ce qui concerne les « propositions », je pense qu'il est bien plus important de décrire correctement l'idée que de faire des propositions dans ce type de question. Faire des propositions peut même être problématique dans certains cas, on voit souvent des réponses qui se contentent de corriger la grammaire.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Exact !

Comment: Pour mes frères et sœurs qui n'ont pas l'anglais naturel, quelques (bonnes ??) idées : http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=+any+two+of+three+

Answer (score 7):

En français, l'équivalent est "deux des trois".

On dit "Deux des trois portes sont noires." *(je ne saurais traduire clairement les exemples cités dans la question, si quelqu'un sait, libre à lui d'éditer cette reponse)*.

Cela fonctionne avec tous les nombres : "un des quatre", "cinq des quinze", etc...

Comment: Plus ou moins. Ton exemple montre que sur trois portes, il y en a deux noires, mais ce sont toujours les mêmes (portes 1 et 3, par exemple). L'idée de la question était de trouver comment dire "Sur les trois personnes qui ont accès au compte bancaire de la société, *n'importe quelle combinaison de deux personnes dans ces trois* peuvent décider de clôturer le compte. Il y a une notion de combinaison (équivalente à la combinatoire des mathématiques). *deux des trois* est la traduction de *two of three*, mais comment traduire *any two of three* ?

Comment: "Sur les trois personnes qui ont accès au compte bancaire de la société, *deux de ces trois personnes* peuvent décider de clôturer le compte." Cela marche aussi avec cet exemple, non ?
Je viens de me rendre compte en écrivant que ça ne va pas... Je ne connais pas de réelle expression distincte pour ce cas là, donc.

Comment: @SteeveDroz: "*sur trois portes, il y en a deux noires, mais ce sont toujours les mêmes*". Non, cette réponse est pertinente (remplacez noires par ouvertes). Ex: [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_couronne_(cyclisme)) "*Certains cyclistes ont été tout près de remporter la triple couronne en remplissant deux des trois conditions*". Il est clair que ça peut être n'importe lesquelles, et pas forcément les mêmes pour chacun des coureurs.

Answer (score 7):

dans certains contextes, "deux parmi trois"

Comment: Je dirais même dans tous les contextes proposés dans la question. "Les signatures de deux membres parmi les trois du conseil" et "une mesure entre deux ports parmi les trois entrées du panneau avant".

Answer (score 4):

*Two of three [things]* se traduit facilement par *deux des trois [choses]*, mais il est souvent difficile de traduire *any two of three things* en français. Et la nuance est *très* importante.

« Deux des trois voitures ont un point commun » et « les voitures de n'importe quelle combinaison de deux voitures parmi les trois ont un point commun » ce n'est pas la même chose. « Deux des trois » désigne deux entités parmi trois, c'est-à-dire une combinaison particulière. *Any two of three things* suggère une combinaison *quelconque* parmi *toutes* les combinaisons.

J'ai utilisé « les voitures de n'importe quelle combinaison de *n* [voitures] parmi les *m* ». C'est une traduction qui fonctionnera à peu près partout, mais ça peut paraitre lourd… très lourd.

Dans un contexte scientifique cela conviendra surement, mais que ce soit dans les exemples qui ont été évoqués dans la question, ou de façon générale, je ne vois malheureusement aucune façon de formuler une telle phrase de façon concise sans introduire d'inexactitude. Découper en plusieurs phrases ou propositions serait le choix le plus naturel. Par exemple « Trois membres du conseil auront la possibilité d'apposer leur signature. Deux signatures seulement sont nécessaires pour un retrait d'argent. »

Comment: Une formulation comme _Deux des trois membres appointés à cet effet par le conseil doivent signer les retraits_ n'est ambiguë qu'avec beaucoup de mauvaise foi, mais c'est surtout à cause du _appointés à cet effet_ qui indique que tous ont l'autorisation et parce que si un des appointés doit absolument signer on formulera plus clairement en _la signature du trésorier et d'un des deux commissaires au compte..._.