# Comment dire « any two » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, déterminants, science, conditions

Je me demande comment traduire la phrase

> F vanishes if any two indices are equal.
>
> F est nul si deux indices sont égaux.

La phrase française respecte-t-elle le sens de *any two* ?

Si, par exemple, il y a trois indices en total est-ce mieux de dire :

> F est nul si deux (indices) parmi trois sont égaux.

?

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8012/comment-formuler-l%c3%a9quivalent-de-any-two-of-three-things-en-fran%c3%a7ais

Comment: Once again, the answer will be highly dependent on the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I**

Oui, votre phrase française respecte le sens de « any two ».

Un autre moyen de traduire « any two » consiste à utiliser l'idée des paires, idée issue de la théorie des ensembles; ainsi la première phrase se traduit comme suit;

« F est nul pour **toute paire** d'indices égaux. »

Dans le cas de cette première phrase, comme dans l'original anglais, on n'implique pas que seulement deux des indices doivent être égaux pour que F soit nul.

**II**

Tout d'abord, lorsque l'on sait qu'il y a trois indices on ne dit pas  « F est nul si deux (indices) parmi trois sont égaux. »,

mais on dit

« F est nul si deux des trois indices sont égaux. » (1) ;

si on veut conserver « parmi », ce qui n'est pas un inconvénient, on a aussi la possibilité de dire

« Si parmi les trois indices deux sont égaux (alors) F est nul. » (2).

Ajouter « alors » est préférable comme les assertions de type « if…then » en anglais ont traditionnellement la traduction « si…alors » en français, cependant les phrases restent correctes et très acceptables sans « alors » (aussi un peu une question de choix personnel devrait-on dire).

Une forme qui pourrait impliquer la nécessité que pas plus de  deux indices soient égaux est la suivante :

« F est nul si sur les trois indices deux sont égaux. ».

Cependant cela est discutable : doit-on considérer « sur » comme connotant l'expression d'un ratio ou doit-on le considérer comme désignant l'ensemble des indices parmi lesquels il faut en reconnaitre au moins deux comme étant égaux? Cela rappelle que le langage courant est trompeur en mathématiques et que le seul recours qui vaille la peine de nos efforts reste le langage de la logique mathématique.

Le mot « indices » ne doit être omis que si dans ce qui précède immédiatement au cours de la discussion est à propos des trois indices.

Dans les possibilités (1) et (2) qui viennent d'être listées l'éventualité que le troisième index soit aussi égal aux deux autres n'est pas exclue, comme ça ne l'est pas non plus dans l'original, cependant on rend clair un tel contexte en ajoutant « au moins » à « deux » ( au moins deux) et il serait donc selon mon opinion préférable de formuler l'idée en prenant cela en compte.

exemple :  F est nul si **au moins** deux des trois indices sont égaux.

Dans votre dernière  phrase (F est nul si deux (indices) parmi trois sont égaux.), -- laquelle ne me semble pas correcte du point de vue syntaxe -- la possibilité de l'égalité du troisième index n'est pas exclue et cela correspond à l'anglais ; si vous vouliez exprimer l'éventualité de l'impossibilité de l'égalité des trois indices vous pourriez le faire clairement comme ceci :

« F est nul si parmi les trois indices  **deux et au plus deux** sont égaux. » ou bien (totalement équivalent)

« F est nul si deux des trois indices, **et au plus deux**, sont égaux. ».

III

Le choix entre « F est nul » et « F s'annule » (sens équivalent) est largement une question de choix personnel en se rappelant qu'il existe chez les auteurs une assez forte prépondérance pour l'utilisation de la seconde possibilité (à laquelle on peut reprocher une certaine ''artificialité'').
On ne trouve pas « F disparait » dans les mathématiques françaises; ce terme correspond littéralement à « F vanishes » mais on doit noter que cette terminologie anglo-saxonne est assez  extravagante et doit être issue des applications des mathématiques quand une valeur « zéro » peut correspondre à un effet que l'on considèrera comme nul ou non existant; cependant une fonction dont les valeurs sont zéro est sans aucune ambigüité défini pour ces valeurs et dans les applications correspond toujours à un phénomène réel.

Answer (score 3):

Dans la deuxième traduction, *F est nul si deux (indices) parmi trois sont égaux.* vous ajoutez une notion qui n'est pas présente en anglais : vous excluez le cas des trois indices égaux pour la nullité de F. En effet la phrase peut s'entendre comme *F est nul si deux (indices) parmi trois sont égaux, et deux seulement.*

Par ailleurs, en fonction du contexte, la traduction de *F vanishes* pourrait être plutôt *F disparait* ou *F s'annule*, et *indices* peut être le pluriel de *index* qui en français est invariable.

Pour la traduction de *any two indices*, j'opterais pour:

> F s'annule si deux quelconques des indices (ou index) sont égaux.